# How can I append to log files in this simple Java Logging implementation?

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I got the following class to create and manage a `Logger`. Whenever across the code and program execution, calls to static `getLogger()` *catch blocks* are used to log.

```
public class Log {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");  

    public static void iniciarLog() throws IOException {
        FileHandler fh;  

        try { 
//          fh = new FileHandler(System.getProperty("user.home")+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"TorrentDownloader.log");  
            fh = new FileHandler("%h/TorrentDownloader.log");  
            logger.addHandler(fh);
            SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
            fh.setFormatter(formatter);  

            logger.info("Se inició el log"); 
        } catch (SecurityException | IOException e) {  
            logger.severe("Error al crear el log");
        } 
    }

    public static Logger getLogger() {
        return logger;
    }
}
```

However, how can I append to such logging file? All examples I've seen change a lot this implementation which I like as it's clear, brief and simple.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the `FileHandler` [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html#FileHandler%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29), you can specify a `boolean` to specify an append mode.

Do as following:

```
fh = new FileHandler("%h/TorrentDownloader.log", true);
```

Comment: Thanks, can you extend more about the `count` parameter?

Comment: Oops ... my bad, i misread the documentation, it's a default behaviour. I will update my answer.

Comment: But, how would it change to use that constructor giving a different count?

Comment: It limit the number of files created with the limit parameter. Check the link in my answer for more information.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, do you have experience with FX and data binding? I got this doubt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730904/how-to-properly-use-javafx-tableview-and-observablelist-classes

Answer (score 2):

Use a different constructor

```
fh = new FileHandler("%h/TorrentDownloader.log", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this constructor:

```
FileHandler handler = new FileHandler(String pattern, boolean append);
```

and in your case, it's:

```
fh = new FileHandler("%h/TorrentDownloader.log", true);
```

This constructor creates a FileHandler with a file name pattern, and a boolean telling whether the FileHandler should append to any existing files or not.

And this [article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/handlers.html) has a full explanation.