# How to properly use JavaFX TableView and ObservableList classes?

Tags: java, binding, tableview, javafx-8

I got a class where I receive some collection structure:

```
public class YIFY {

    private static List<Pelicula> resultados;

    public static void setResultados(List<Pelicula> resultados) {
        YIFY.resultados = resultados;
    }

}
```

Later, at another class I *associate* the contents of such `List` to a `TableView`. However I create an `FXCollections.observableArrayList()` which is set as the bind element to the table.

This is how I do it:

```
    peliculas = FXCollections.observableArrayList(YIFY.getResultados());

    tituloColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("titulo"));
    calidadColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("calidad"));
    imdbColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("imdbLink"));
    añoColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("año"));
    tableResultados.setItems(peliculas);
```

Where tableResultados is a `TableView` and peliculas declared as an `ObservableList<Pelicula>` naturally not initialized.

What I hate and I think is just not that OK is that when I need to change/update `resultados` at `YIFY` class, I also need to do:

```
peliculas.clear();
peliculas.setAll(YIFY.getResultados());
```

I think it all should be an ***`Observable`*** since the beginning at `YIFY` class, what I tried but I got MUCH problems as I didn't find along the Java docs a proper class implementation which was not abstract so I wouldn't have to implement any extra method.

How can I manage this? Is my approach ok?

Comment: Making the list in the YIFY class an ObservableList sounds like the approach you need. I don't really understand what the problem you had was when you tried to do that.

Comment: I didn't find along the Java docs a proper class implementation which was not abstract so I wouldn't have to implement any extra method.

Comment: Why don't you just initialize it with `FXCollections.observableArrayList()`?

Comment: `ObservableList<Pelicula> resultados = FXCollections.observableArrayList();`  Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I really understand the question, but what's wrong with

```
public class YIFY {
    private static ObservableList<Pelicula> resultados = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public static void setResultados(List<Pelicula> resultados) {
        YIFY.resultados.setAll(resultados);
    }
}
```

Comment: `setAll` wil always replace the current value, right?

Comment: [`setAll(...)` will set all the elements of the list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#setAll-java.util.Collection-)

Comment: [See docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#setAll-java.util.Collection-)